# Does it take long compilation time if every files including "assert.h"?

Tags: c++, compilation

Based on Mats Petersson's results, I did some tests. My work on turning the assert on and off by defining a macro is not necessary. My conclusions are:

1. Including standard headers such as `<cassert>`, `<vector>`, `<memory>` and so on, takes little compilation time. We don't need to care.
2. Be careful in including your own files. Include those that are really needed because the dependent requires recompilation after the change of the depended.
3. Be careful when including collection headers of class library, such as `<QWidgets>` (Qt header to include all its widgets). This takes a huge time in compilation.

[Original Post]

Does it take long compilation time if every files includes "assert.h"? I think similar questions on "math.h" or other common files. I don't like pre-compiled header. This happens when I have a Vector3D class which represents a vector in 3D space with x, y, z component. The class is used almost everywhere. I have a function named `component(int i)` where `i` is asserted between 0 and 2. For performance reason, I don't put its implementation in cpp file. Thus "assert.h" is included almost everywhere.

```
#pragma once

#include <assert.h>

/// A vector in a 3D space with 3 components: x, y, and z.
class Vector3D
{
public:
    Vector3D(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0)
    {
        m_component[0] = x;
        m_component[1] = y;
        m_component[2] = z;
    }

    float x() const    {return m_component[0];}
    float y() const    {return m_component[1];}
    float z() const    {return m_component[2];}

    void setX(float x)    {m_component[0] = x;}
    void setY(float y)    {m_component[1] = y;}
    void setZ(float z)    {m_component[2] = z;}

    float component(int i) const
    {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < 3);
        return m_component[i];
    }

    float& component(int i)
    {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < 3);
        return m_component[i];
    }

private:
    float m_component[3];
};
```

Inspired by Floris Velleman, I add a file to define my ASSERT to turn on and off it. It requires changing `assert` to `ASSERT` in the code using assert. Thanks.

```
#ifdef USE_ASSERT
# include <assert.h>
# define ASSERT(statement) assert(statement)
#else
# define ASSERT(statement)
#endif
```

Comment: Don't do circular includes then.

Comment: If it's common to everything, chuck it in your precompiled header.

Comment: If you really have some kind of reason not to use "assert.h" you could use an if statement to check the i variable. If it turns out it doesn't fall in the region (the else) you could throw a (custom) error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All headers use the same inclusion model, which is tremendously slow. Some headers may be more complex than others, but in general, you don't include a header you don't need.

Comment: "Tremendously slow" ?  Care to quantify that statement a bit?  But I do agree that you should not include unneeded headers.

Comment: @fvu Just try to include several headers of Boost library and see for yourself ;)

Comment: It is slow relative to other mechanisms, take a look at a bunch of C++ code that has to #include <windows.h> everywhere vs. other languages like C# where declarations are resolved recursively.

Comment: @fvu: Compared to more modernly designed languages, the preprocessor's include mechanism is quite slow. See [this well-written article by Wlater Bright](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-compilation-speed/228701711).

Comment: Please do have a look at my results below. Unless you are compiling files across a network or some other such thing that increases the "open and read file" time dramatically, it's pretty small difference - if I can't measure it over 30 files that all include assert.h or cassert once each.

Comment: @MatsPetersson `assert.h` is at most 100 short SLOC, almost all of which are comments and preprocessor directives, so it's not surprising it doesn't add much overhead. For larger headers with lots of actual code/declarations, it gets more severe. Try your benchmark with `<iostream>`, for example. Note that the problem isn't (just) that it repeatedly *reads* some files, but that it has to repeatedly do complicated preprocessing and parsing on every single file's entire contents, recursively including everything that file includes.

Comment: Yes, and the original question was "does including assert.h make my compile slower", and my answer is "yes, but it's milliseconds on something that takes several seconds". Obviously, not including huge files ["windows.h" is a good example of that] when you don't actually use it is worthwhile worrying about - but the whole idea of "lets remove header files in to speed up the compile", you'll get much more out of spending your time finding some cheap memory and increasing the amount of RAM so the system can cache better, etc.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: 30 files? Try 30,000 or 300,000 files, which is a much more realistic size.

Comment: Yes, if you are compiling 30k files, it will add 3ms per file, and it will take a whole 10 seconds longer than without. But assuming your 30k files are completely empty, but contain some useful code, you probably also want that compiled. Given that 30 files of mine take 7 soconds, we're looking at about 2 hours. Or do you have some evidence that shows otherwise, please show us!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it takes, on my machine, 0.03 seconds more per file (0.1s in total, over 30 files, containing either `#include <assert.h>` or `//#include <assert.h>` and a large comment of about 90 lines to fill the file out. I copied that 30 times over to separate .c files, and compile with `gcc -c *.c`.

However, that's pretty much "nothing" compiled. If we instead take some real C++ code, so the compiler has to "think" a bit, what happens:

Baseline (source xx.cpp - around 280 lines of C++ code in a standalone program, copied 30 times to files called xx1.cpp .. xx30.cpp, compile with `g++ -O2 -c *.cpp`):

```
7.722s      7.730s      7.660s
```

Add `#include <cassert>` at the end of the list of

```
7.734s      7.652s      7.676s
```

I don't think that's a significant change. I'm sure if you do `#include <assert.h>` in every header file, and include hundreds or thousands of header files, that ALL include assert.h, maybe it will make a difference. But I'm doubting anyone would be able to measure a real difference on a real project.

Comment: I appreciate your work but didn't get your point. Do you mean with including `assert.h`, it takes 0.003 s more per file? (0.1/30 is about 0.003)

Comment: Yes, give or take a millisecond or to. This is with local files. Obviously, if the files are held on a server somewhere remotely, then that will add to the compile time. But for a "real" compile, it really doesn't make any difference, because the compiler spends a lot of time "thinking" about what code to generate, and not much time reading files.

Answer (score 2):

The standard header `assert.h` (you're using angle brackets instead of quotes, so I'm assuming you're talking about standard C assert header) is one of the smallest headers from all standard C library, so in this case it really doesn't matter. Usefulness of assertions is more important than whatever speed you're likely to gain.

Note: in C++ `cassert` is used instead of `assert.h`.

Big and convoluted headers like iostream the other hand...

Answer (score 1):

```
 #ifndef AssertIncluded
 #define AssertIncluded
 #include "assert.h"
 #endif
```

Not 100% sure about the syntax but this will likely get rid of double including things. As for speed, compilation time increases according to the amount of things that have to happen. Including more files means: "longer compilation time".

Comment: Surely this logic should reside in `assert.h` for it's *own* correctness?

Comment: @GManNickG Quoting the GCC assert.h "We should be able to include this file multiple times to allow the assert macro to be enabled/disabled for different parts of code.  So don't add a header guard.". So... yeah, it shouldn't.